# Do I need to download tools for visual studio 2017 preview again if I have Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am new to Visual Studio.

I wanted to use its python tools. But I learned that python tools were available only with preview version of Visual Studio 2017 only after I finished downloading tools for Visual Studio 2017(stable version).

If I download only the python tools along with visual studio 2017 preview, and I wanted to do a project that might use a combination of the python tools and some other tools (lets say xamarin tools) that I downloaded earlier for Visual Studio 2017, 
do I need to download those tools again for the preview, or can I use the tools I downloaded earlier with the stable version and use them with my python tools in the preview version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see in the following post:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2017/02/22/python-in-vs2017/